# How can I add a .props file to a C# project?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

I am trying to set up continuous delivery of Azure Web Jobs, and came across [this post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/18/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/) from the Azure blog. One of the steps there is to add a .props file to the web job application's properties.

I am having difficulty adding a .props file. My web searches indicate that props files are only applicable to C++ projects. But I think the web job project in the blog post is built with C#.

Comment: How about "Add New Item->Text File"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding in this article it is enough that you add a new text och xml file and name it WebJobs.props. Look also at the screenshot explaining how you should edit it. Here is a different example of this file. https://github.com/davidebbo-test/WebAppWithWebJobsVS/commit/15e7579075312d620fe42a8746503ba82adf5305